# Appsync offline queries not working in android

Tags: android, aws-appsync, offline-caching

I am creating the android APP using '**com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.10.0**' android library. When I am using the 'NETWORK_FIRST' option (when network is on) queries and mutations are working well, but when I am using the same in offline mode I am getting following issues:

1). OPTION used 'CACHE_AND_NETWORK' the error I am getting "com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloNetworkException: Failed to execute http call" error and my mutations not getting fired.

2). OPTION used 'CACHE_ONLY' then sometimes I am getting null response or my cache does not get updated.

My App includes queries and mutations for large set of data.

so How can I manage queries and mutations in offline mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can report your bug here for the team to take a look at: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android